# How do I make a variable empty in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to empty a used variable in Prolog.
For example, I want to do like this:

```
i = null;
```

but in Prolog.

How do I do this?

Comment: Explain why do you want this?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do that with pure prolog variables; once a variable is instantiated its value cannot change.

You could use [global variables](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=gvar), but I strongly recommend to try to think a less imperative way to write the program.

edit: check  DaveEdelstein's comment too

Comment: I agree that there is no command you can use to change a variable once it is bound.  What you can do though, is force backtracking through the assignment, then this variable can be set again.  I'm pretty sure OP was not looking for this kind of answer though...

Answer (score 0):

Prolog has assign-once variables. That is any particular variable in Prolog can only ever get one value assigned to it.  A Prolog variable at any point in execution either has a value, which can thereafter never be changed.

Comment: To be clear, assign once doesn't mean that the assigned term cannot be further instantiated and thus, in a way, changed. Consider as an example the following query, which succeeds: `X = f(a,Y), X = f(Z,1)`.